# Отступ в зависимости от высоты элемента position: fixed

Tags: css, position

Требуется реализовать вертикальное позиционирование `div#content` относительно `div#top` таким образом, что если высота `div#top` будет увеличена, то `div#content` тоже опустился бы по нижней его границе. Аналогично, как опускается `div#menu`.
`position: fixed/absolute` мешает такому поведению, но `div#top` и `div#menu` должны быть зафиксированы на странице.
Ищу вариант решения исключительно на `CSS`, если это вообще возможно.

```
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            border: solid 1px grey;
            font-size: 50px;
            color: pink;
        }

        body {
            width: 1000px;
        }

        #wrapper {
            width: inherit;
        }

        #fixed {
            position: fixed;
            width: inherit;
        }

        #top {
            width: inherit;
        }

        #menu {
            float: left;
            width: 30%;
        }

        #content {
            position: relative;
            margin-left: 30%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="fixed">
            <div id="top">
                TOP NAV BAR TOP NAV BAR TOP NAV BAR TOP NAV BAR
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                MENU NAV
                MENU NAV
                MENU NAV
                MENU NAV
                MENU NAV
                MENU NAV
                MENU NAV
                MENU NAV
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
            CONTENT MOTHERFATHER
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Лучше всего будет дать вашему `div#fixed` фиксированную высоту(не обязательно в `px`), а в медиа запросах менять её. Тогда с помощью `css` вы сможете гарантированно держать `div#content` под зафиксированном элементом.

Comment: Расширим проблематику, взяв за пример кейс, когда содержимое div#top будет увеличено динамически (изменится после загрузки страницы, например, в результате ajax-запроса), его контент разъедется на две и более строк, высота блока увеличится. Тогда div#menu опустится, а div#content - нет.
Полагаю, медиа-запросами тут не решить, ведь они отслеживают изменение габаритов окна.